# NodeJS render html file with form not working on angular side

Tags: node.js, angular, angular8

I am using ExpressJS with EJS template view engine. I am trying to show an HTML file on the angular component, but the form tag and its child input tag do not work on the angular side. They show only label data.

**On NodeJS**

**agreementController.js**

```
exports.getAgreementHtml = async (request, response, next) => {
    const params = request.query
    let reqPath = path.join(__dirname, '../agreements');
    var agreementObj = {
        user: { email: "example@gmail.com" }
    }
    // render domestic rent html
    ejs.renderFile(reqPath + '/domestic_rent.ejs', agreementObj, {}, function (err, str) {
        if (err !== null) {
            responseObj.status = errorCodes.DATA_NOT_FOUND
            responseObj.message = language.getMessage('NO_RECORD_FOUND')
            response.send(responseObj)
            return
        }

        responseObj.status = errorCodes.OK
        responseObj.data = str
        response.send(responseObj);
        return;
    });
}
```

**domestic_rent.js**

```
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p><%= user.email %></p>
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="test" required name="test">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**On Angular 8 Side**

**agreement-show.component.ts**

```
  getAgreementData() {
    const params = {
      id: this.agreementId
    };
    this.agreementService.getAgreementHtml(params).subscribe(
      (result) => {
        console.log('result agreement data::: ', result);
        if (result.status !== 200) {
          this.commonService.change.emit({ status: 'error', message: 'unknown error' });
          return;
        }
        this.someHtml = result.data;
        return;
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
        this.commonService.change.emit({ status: 'error', message: error.message });
      }
    );
  }
```

**agreement-show.component.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="someHtml"></div>
```

[Output Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAcbQ.png)

Comment: Can you give more detail as to the error or what type of output is occurring?

Comment: @Nelles I have added output attachment in the question, please check

Comment: Where is nodeJS coming from in this question, looking at code your angular module is not working as expected. Did you check if your API is responding properly with expected data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using **ElementRef** function we can add html runtime.
Please use following step:

```
        @ViewChild('showitems') showitems: ElementRef;

        const elemt: HTMLElement = this.showitems.nativeElement;
        this.someHtml = result.data;
        elemt.innerHTML = this.someHtml;
```